# Invoice Design - How to?

Tags: invoice, pdf, print, create-invoice

I'm living in Turkey and our legal systems are sucks. Maybe some of you heard of it.
Anyway.

I have to edit magento's standard invoice template to this;

[image]

How can i do this? 
When it comes invoices, im just a fool.

Answer (score 2):

Magento  invoice pdf design from class `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice`
 and `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract` and Zend PDF.You need customizayion  on those classes.

atwix has been describe in briefly.Please check at http://www.atwix.com/magento/customize-magento-pdf-invoice-and-packingslip/